# Save overflowing text and put on different text object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, text

[UNITY C#]

I have one string (a large one) of the contents in a book. I want to display this string in the text on page one. However, when the page one text overflows I want to display the overflowing words in the text on page two.

[Page One Text Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xIlt.png)

[Page Two Text Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J8xUw.png)

For example, the text below that goes off the page should go on page two.

[Overflowing text image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YC6q2.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
text01.text  = someString;

//force canvas update so we can get correct result from cachedTextGenerator
Canvas.ForceUpdateCanvases ();
int  truncateIndex  = text01.cachedTextGenerator.characterCountVisible;

text01Continued.text = someString.Substring (truncateIndex);
```

This solved my problems!
Credit to **tlutz** in this answer: https://forum.unity.com/threads/get-truncated-string.324412/